# How to load a video file using Opencv in java

Tags: java, file, opencv, video, load

I am trying to use opencv to load a video file in Java using netbeans. Does anybody know a way of doing it? I can't find solutions searching online.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add **C:\opencv\build\x86\vc11\bin** to the Path variable...
and the write:

```
 private void myMethod(...) {
    Mat frame = new Mat();
    VideoCapture camera = new VideoCapture("C:/MyName/MyPc/Desktop/TheLordOfTheRings.mp4");
    JFrame jframe = new JFrame("MyTitle");
    jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JLabel vidpanel = new JLabel();
    jframe.setContentPane(vidpanel);
    jframe.setVisible(true);

    while (true) {
        if (camera.read(frame)) {

            ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(Mat2bufferedImage(frame));
            vidpanel.setIcon(image);
            vidpanel.repaint();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll test the code and give you a feedback.

Comment: Are there any arguments in the method?